# drupal commerce customize node product list

Tags: commerce

I'm trying to modify the theme file "node--product--type--product--list.tpl.php" to customize the layout.

I'm having a little trouble doing it,

can someone please point out, how I can access easily to each field ?

I would need the fields : title, price, images, link to the product.

Comment: `$node->content['product:title']` and so on...

Comment: I don't seems to have access to $node variable in there... However I do have access to the $content variable, so able to get each fields, but it really seems to be a pain to get each raw fields in order to display them !

Comment: It is actually the "and so on..." I'm looking for ;-) any documentation about that ? I really would like to RTFM :-)

Comment: print render($content['product:title_field']); doesn't seems to work

Answer (score 0):

As I see from your question you need to access the field info of a product. You can do it at `template.php` file. Just do it in the **preprocess** function based on the TPL file where you are going to use after you get it and put it in some variable. I will give example here for [THEME_preprocess_node()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.module/function/template_preprocess_node/7).

```
function THEME_preprocess_node(&$vars){
  if ($node = menu_get_object()){
    if($node->type == 'PRODUCT_display'){
      $product_id = $node->field_PRODUCT_reference[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['product_id'];//here mention your own product reference field name.
      $product = commerce_product_load($product_id);//After this you will have all the product info in $product variable, even fields.
      $author = $product->field_book_author[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'];
      $vars['author'] = $author;
}
```

After this you will have `$author` variable in your all `node.tpl.php`, use it in the way you want. You can even modify info at `template.php` file itself if you want. I hope it helps, otherwise you can comment for more help :)